# How to navigate between related files?

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, user-behavior

I am trying to design functionality that allows the user to easily navigate from one file to another within a "master file".

There is currently a correlation between one another, such as the parent having children files.

I've come up with this to navigate between, but it's not entirely working for the use-case.

[image]

Wondering possible variations for navigation that's similar to this, but may tie in better?

Tree navigation is not possible because there may be sharing of masters for different category of children i.e., a child may have two masters.

Comment: I think if you could provide a more substantive use case we might be better able to give you some ideas.

Comment: Search for "tree navigation" on google or bing images. And then do the same on pinterest and other curation sites. You'll probably find something that resonates.

Comment: What's the larger screen look like? That could help get you some more targeted answers. Right now you have just a menu, but wondering if you can provide more of the view

Comment: What is a "master file" and what is the relationship of these other files within it to each other, to the master, and to these other masters?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problems is seen in Adobe Muse and other Adobe applications where there is separate section for masters with an alias to them such as "master-A" and "master-B" and these aliases are linked to the children.

As you can see from the image, there is section of masters in the bottom and their' alias are been linked to the children.

[image]